# Sending Many POST requests simultaneously Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, node-modules

I am new to Nodejs so excuse me for any mistake .. :)

Let me explain what i am trying to do :

basically i am making a push notification service for my platform .. i will explain further..
I have two NodeJs servers (using express) :

**SERVER 1** :
it gets everything needed from the database such as ( device registration , identifier ..) and should send to the second server.

**SERVER 2** : This server Receives a JSON ( contains everything i need ) to create the FCM and APNS payload and then send to the convenient provider (FCM,APNS).

**what i am using** : i am using **axios** to send POST requests.

**The issue** : since the 1st server will be sending big amount of requests ( usually 5K or more -- it's dynamic) at the same time , axios cannot handle that , and I've tried many other alternatives to axios but faced the same thing.

**My question** : How can i send that amount of requests without any issues ?

**PS:** when i send few requests ( 100 or bit more) i face no errors ...

I hope everything is clear and i  would really appreciate any help.

**Code Example of the Request with Axios :**

**PS:** it always falls in the "[Request Error] ..."

```
    try
                {
          
                  axios.post(endpoint,{sendPushRequest})
                        .then( response => {
                            console.log(response.data);
                        })
                        .catch(  er => {

                            if (er.response) {
                                console.log("[Response Error] on sending  to Dispatcher...");
                                // The request was made and the server responded with a status code
                                // that falls out of the range of 2xx

                                console.log(er.response.data);
                                console.log(er.response.status);
                                console.log(er.response.headers);

                            } else if (er.request) {
                                console.log("[Request Error] on sending  to Dispatcher...");
                                
                                // The request was made but no response was received
                                // `error.request` is an instance of XMLHttpRequest in the browser and an instance of
                               
                                
                            } else {
                                // Something happened in setting up the request that triggered an Error
                                console.log('[Error]', er.message);
                            }
                            console.log(er.config);
                        });
                }
                catch (e) {
                    console.log('[ Catch Error]', e);
                }
```

Comment: Hmmm, I'm fairly confident Node and Axios can send 5k requests simultaneously. On the other hand, if all requests are being sent to the same server, this server probably feels bombed and enters DDoS protection mode to avoid crashing... Any reason _why_ you absolutely need to send 5k requests simultaneously? Also what is Axios's error message and reason for failing?

Comment: Also, recently I got a lot of trouble with Axios. Apparently there's [an old known and yet unfixed bug](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/2527) that makes some requests randomly hang forever without throwing an error. I got rid of Axios and started using [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) instead, and it works like a charm.

Comment: Okay so , why i need to send 5k ? because the platform is used by client and when he created a campaign to send to his users , i should send as much as possible in short period of time.
i will post the AXIOS error message ( it is quite long but ill post it )

Comment: So you are making 5k POST requests to 5k different servers? Even then, why do you need all requests to be _simultaneous_? Can't you afford them 100 at a time?

Comment: no i have two servers , one to is the request sender , and the second is the reciver

Comment: having 100 at a time will take too long to send 1M push notifications that needs to be sent for example

Comment: So I don't understand why you need to make 5k requests between two servers. I can't imagine a business logic that implies one server to absolutely bomb another with thousands of simultaneous requests. Please enlighten me

Comment: Like, if server 1 needs to ask server 2, "Hey, send one message to all these 5000 users", why would you need 5000 requests for this?? Only one request containing all 5000 email addresses would do the trick. Really I'm puzzled about the "requirement" to bomb server 2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224856/discussion-between-mohamed-ali-nakouri-and-jeremy-thille).

Comment: Hmmm, no thank you, allow me to decline. I'm busy on other things, I was just passing by :)

Comment: okay , no problem , thanks anyway , have a good day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, for doing this kind of asynchronous stuff you should use any queuing service as if the second server gets busy which it might in case of handling such a huge number of rest APIs your user would miss the notification.

Your flow should be like:

SERVER 1: it gets everything needed from the database such as ( device registration, identifier ..) and should **push/publish to any queuing service** such as rabbitMQ/Google pubsub etc.

SERVER 2: Instead of having rest APIs, this server should pull messages from the queue recursively and then Receives a JSON ( contains everything I need ) to create the FCM and APNS payload and then send to the convenient provider (FCM, APNS).

This is beneficial because even if anything happens to your server like busy/crashes the message would persist in the queue and on restarting the server you would be able to do your work(sending a notification or whatever).

Comment: Thank you , i will try this and see what happens , but what you said makes more sense